# Jquery PageSlide Direction Left not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, right-to-left

i've found this example from: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/
it pretty good, just have one problem, when set the direction to the left, the navigation will overlap the content.

Slide form left to right is working good, but when right to left it having this issue.
Anyway to make it don't overlap the content? or other solution for this effect?
Please help, thank you~

as per images:

[image: before]

[image: after]

Code that i set it to left:

```
<script>
    $(".open").pageslide({direction: "left"});
</script>
```

**Demo** but don't know why not working at jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/CandiceYap/xL5rw/

Comment: Are you including their css file? It's hard to tell whats wrong from 1 line of code which is exactly what they have on their site. Throw it in a jsfiddle or something and I'll give it a better look.

Comment: Hi i attach the jsfiddle already, but not sure why not working at there...

Comment: Hmm weird. I'll give it a look for you in a couple minutes when I have more free time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it opposite you might change left to right to make it in the left.

```
<script>
$(".open").pageslide( {direction : "right"} );
</script>
```

Comment: lala90 wants it to slide from right to left, so `( {direction : "left"} )` is the correct code for a right to left slider.

Comment: Okay so give me reputation :)

Comment: not really sure, but i'm assuming he's forgetting the stylesheet. We will never know unless he posts more code.

Comment: I think it's is working ( {direction : "right"} ) I have checked I have the same pageslider You check also

Comment: Could you please give me reputation I want to get teacher tag :)